# Why mv --backup does not work on CentOS 7?

Tags: linux, centos, mv

I tried doing something like

`mv --backup=numbered KeyStoreAll.jks .old/KeyStoreAll.jks`

which works flawlessly on Ubuntu 18.04.

But when I'm trying the same on CentOS 7 it asks me

`mv: overwrite ‘.old/KeyStoreAll.jks’?`

Why it does not work for CentOS 7?

mv help/syntax looks the same.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your aliases definition:

```
$ touch source 
$ touch target
$ mv source target

$ alias mv='mv -i'
$ touch source
$ mv source target
mv: overwrite ‘target’?
```